# Why do night sky appear red when it is cloudy?

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science, light-pollution

Since childhood, I have seen that whenever at night, the sky is cloudy, the sky becomes red. But, clouds are grayish, so it is expected that the sky becomes more darker. But no, it is not! Why does this happen? Is wavelength of various colours linked to it? I'm even not sure what tag to give!!

Comment: [this thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137189/23473) should answer your question

Comment: I'm asking of cloudy skies..

Comment: How far into the night is this? Midnight? Dusk? Dawn?

Comment: Yes. At anytime between, say, 9 pm to 3 am

Comment: Do you live in a city?

Comment: Yes I live in calcutta

Comment: Lots of street lights?

Comment: Like any city in india!! Yes..

Comment: The light from the city reflects off the clouds

Comment: Oh I see, then it must appear dark in rural parts?

Comment: Oh yes, you can't see your hand in front of your face on a cloudy night in rural areas

Comment: City lights are major sources of [light pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_pollution)

Comment: I see. Actually I have poor experience of a cloudy night in rural areas.  By the way I expected a more complex situation right there, but it turns out to be so simple! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colour you see in the sky on cloudy nights is due to the reflection of city lights off the clouds. In rural areas, a cloudy night is, as you expected, significantly darker.

[image]

However, the massive amount of light given off in urban areas reflects back to Earth when there is cloud cover.

[image]

And so, you see a red-orange hue, similar to the overall colour of the city lights.