# Why is the sky never green?But it can be slightly blue-green?

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science

The colour of the sky is determined by light scattered from the sun reaching the earth from a new direction. The shorter the wavelength the greater the light is scattered. On a dull day, with the sun obscured by cloud, with more moisture in the air, the scattered light could extend beyond the blue to include some green light. Because the light most scattered is blue with in this situation some green, I would expect to see a cyan, perhaps bluish cyan, sky.

Has anyone else seen a cyan sky, perhaps with high thin cloud above an overcast/ cloudy day?

Ron

Comment: This Scientific American article might be of interest? http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-if-sky-is-green-run-for-cover-tornado-is-coming/

Comment: Related:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137189/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137189/59023)

Comment: As per my answer to the other question: The sky is *always* green at night