# Why do we see only the sun as yellowish or orangish? Why not stars, because both of their light undergoes atmospheric refraction?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, atmospheric-science

We see the colour of the sun as yellow to orangish on an average due to its light getting refracted due to the atmosphere. Then why do we see stars as white and not colourful, because light coming from stars also undergoes atmospheric refraction?

Comment: I disagree. The Sun looks white when it's high in the sky, but at that time it's generally too bright to look at for more than a tiny fraction of a second. All celestial bodies look red, orange, or yellow when their altitude (angle above the horizon) is low. Some stars, eg Sirius, can look bluish when they're high in the sky, but some people cannot see the colour of stars.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137189/59023