Why does Sun appear white at noon?
I have found several source citing the reason for the white apperance of sun is due to less scattering of light before sunlight reaches an observer on the Earth (as it is relatively closer to us at noon compared to during sunset and sunrise).
I believe it is not the appropriate reasoning. Shouldn't it be white as light of different wavelengths get's scattered in equal proportions?

See the comments below my answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/137202/59023 for more details...

Here the solar spectrum illustrated graphically.

A furnace on the Earth at a temperature of $5900\,\rm K$, equivalent to light from a flash gun, would appear white and that is the colour of the Sun when observed above the Earth's atmosphere.
When observed on the Earth there is a change due to light scattering, most prominently at the blue end of the spectrum, and absorption by certain gas molecules which are present in the Earth's atmosphere.
The effect of the atmosphere is most prominent when sunlight passes through the greatest thickness of the atmosphere, at sunrise and sunset.

This might help - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atmos/blusky.html
